# Mysql : display one field or another conditionally

Tags: mysql

I have two tables :

> **Table_in_french**
>      - french_value
>
> **Table_translated_value**
>      - french_value
>      - spanish_value

I need to browse Table_in_french and display linked spanish value if it exists or french value if there is no translation available.

I have tried :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (T1.french_value = T2.french_value) THEN spanish_value ELSE T1.french_value END) as label FROM Table_in_french T1, Table_translated_value T2;
```

But I am getting too many duplicates values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are the two tables linked together? Your SQL says `FROM Table2, Table2`...this doesn't seem like you've tried very long.

Comment: You didn't mention field_11 in table2

Comment: My post had some mistakes, I have updated it.

Comment: if (field_11 not in field_21 of Table2) means?

Comment: I have update my post to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this query:    
SELECT (CASE WHEN (T1.french_value = T2.french_value) THEN spanish_value ELSE T1.french_value END) AS label FROM Table_in_french T1 RIGHT JOIN Table_translated_value T2 ON T1.french_value = T2.french_value;
```